# Mori's cone theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I need the proof (reference) of Mori’s theorem about this implication :
Let  $X$ be a projective complex manifold. If $X$ contains no rational curves, then $K_K$ is nef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more precise form of this result is originally due to Miyaoka and Mori, see Theorem 3.6 page 67 in

*Olivier Debarre*: Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry, Universitext. New York, NY: Springer. xiii, 233 p. (2001). [ZBL0978.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0978.14001).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the problem that 
It is not available on the internet
Do you have a pdf version

Comment: I have a paper copy. At any rate, you can find the same result in these GAEL notes by Debarre: https://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/NotesGAEL.pdf

Comment: Okay, thank you so much